# etherparty/explorer issues: "Allow Access to Geth and Refresh the Page"

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, json-rpc, parity, explorers

Does anyone here have experience with the etherparty/explorer blockchain explorer?  I am having trouble connecting.  I keep getting the error message

> *"Allow Access to Geth and Refresh the Page"*

when I access `localhost:8000`.

I was running geth and had the same error messages, but now I am running parity.  Here is how I invoke parity:

```
parity --chain dev  --dapps-apis-all --jsonrpc-cors "http://localhost:8000" --jsonrpc-apis "web3, eth" --jsonrpc-hosts="all" --networkid="<private-number>" --force-ui --ui-no-validation
```

Here is how etherparty/explorer says to invoke geth:

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost:8000"
```

The RPC port is available at localhost:8545.

EDIT: I have since tested with geth, using the main net. I get the same error.  So I am trying other things. Maybe it's how I'm installing (or failing to install) web3?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the jsonrpc-apis flag? Just a thought.

Comment: @5chdn: no it doesn't.  Out of curiosity, why did you think it might?  The doc specifically says to use that.  I'm not criticizing, I just want to know what your thought was.

Comment: Was just thinking maybe some api calls are not accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did all of these things.  But the problem was that the site has to be viewed in a graphical browser.  Since the explorer runs server-side, I was SSHed in and viewing with w3m.  Once I looked at the code pointed out by @Richard Horrocks, it became clear.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but might help...

Poking around at their code, the error is output when [this part](https://github.com/etherparty/explorer/blob/8d90712bcf8a6003a4a2ee15349798827cdb2124/app/app.js#L38) is run:

```
    if(!web3.isConnected()) {
        $('#connectwarning').modal({keyboard:false,backdrop:'static'}) 
        $('#connectwarning').modal('show') 
    }
```

Which implies there's a failure in the following code:

```
var eth_node_url = 'http://localhost:8545'; // TODO: remote URL
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(eth_node_url));
```

Comment: Ah, yes.  So I could hack it by giving that a false positive (since I know web3 is connected.)  Thank you.  I will let you know how it goes tomorrow.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I've updated the answer with a link to the part of their code.

Comment: Or have a look at @5chdn's idea in the comment on the question :-)

Comment: Actually I think I may have failed to install web3.  I thought I did it (ran "bower install" in the parity directory) but maybe not....

Comment: That wasn't it.  I see ""GET /bower_components/web3/dist/web3.min.js" "Mozilla...."  And I have re-installed geth, so it's not parity.  I'm puzzled but I guess I'll just start digging through the code.  BTW when I "fixed" those lines nothing displayed at all.  That's what made me think maybe web3 wasn't available.